# How to declare that the value passed is decorated with a particular type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a `Module` decorator, which allows an object that has a property called `imports` which I want to be an array of other modules. Is there a way to declare that the array should be an array of classes that are decorated with `Module`?

Here are two classes each with the `@Module` decorator. The second one contains an `imports` statement.

```js
@Module()
export class MyModule {}

@Module({ imports: [MyModule] })
export class MyOtherModule {}
```

In this I would like to say that the imports array should be of type `Module` like this:

```js
export interface ModuleOptions {
  imports: Module[];
}

export function Module(options: Partial<ModuleOptions>) {
  return (target: new (...args: any[]) => T) => {
    return class extends target {
    }
  }
}
```

However, that gives me the following errors:

> 'Module' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Module'?
>
> Property 'imports' of exported interface has or is using private name 'Module'.

Comment: What is `Module` *supposed* to be?

Comment: I don't think this is possible at compile-time. But it's definitely possible at runtime.

Comment: I would like to check at compile time. So we know that the type is NOT a module, say if you pass something decorated with `@Injectable()` for example.

Comment: I don't think its possible because decorators do not change the type of the class or "mark" them at all. Decorators are purely runtime. You could try making `Module` a class instead of a decorator and extending that instead.

Comment: It looks like you don't want to the `imports` be instances of `Module` (which is a decorator) but rather have the same type as `Module`s return value. Which currently is just any class - maybe you're looking for a static property as a special marker? Or something? What *are* you actually looking for in them?

Comment: I want them to be `newable` objects that have a `@Module` decorator. But from what it sounds like is that this isn't possible.